# Cowboys and Aliens type TV Movie on SyFy Channel

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am pretty sure I saw this SF-Western on the SyFy Channel a decade or so ago, although I don't know if it was new at the time. I only saw one scene: a town was overrun by insect-like aliens similar to the ones in the *Starship Troopers* films, although I think they were smaller. The alien ship was a globe that hovered in the air and unraveled, dropping the insects onto the ground.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[image: High Plains Drifters DVD cover]

I believe this is the SyFy original movie "High Plains Invaders" from 2009. The aliens in the film do resemble a smaller version of the Arachnids from Starship Troopers.

Their ship is much as you described:
[image]

Comment: That is it. Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't Harry Dresden just hex the machines?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic - Sadly, SyFy canceled his show in late 2007. If only they'd known...

Comment: @T.E.D. (I was referring to the male lead!)